# How to make rest api call with HTTP PUT method in swift

Tags: ios, swift, restkit, put

I have tried the below `REST Api` with `PUT` method.

Here is my code,

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://sampleurl")

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") 

request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"

let session = NSURLSession(configuration:NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

let params:[String: AnyObject] = ["deviceId" : "device_1","mobileDeviceId" : "abcd","deviceType":"ios"]

request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(), error: nil)

let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            //handle error

             print("Parsed error: '\(error)'")
        }
        else {

            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Parsed JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        } 
    }
dataTask.resume()
```

It is not working. Please help me to find out where it is wrong.

Comment: Define 'not working'

Comment: Error description  
Parsed error: 'Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x7a7a8cc0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://smapleurl, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://smapleurl, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x7a6f4520 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1005.)"}'

This error occurs

Comment: It may be a typo but in your `let url = NSURL(string: "http://sampleurl”)` your last `”` is not the correct `"`.

Comment: just a side note, why don't you use POST instead of PUT? sounds like you're posting some values to the server

Answer (score 1):

This is a working code, I send your dictionary as a JSON formatted string to the server, and in the server, I parse the request and build another JSON object that contains the same values as the request, and send them back to the app. In the app, I parse the response and print the results:

```
 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let url = "http://localhost:8080/yourServerGoesHere/putMethodTest"
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"

            let params:[String: AnyObject] = ["deviceId" : "device_1","mobileDeviceId" : "abcd","deviceType":"ios"]
            do{
                request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
                let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
                    if let response = response {
                        let nsHTTPResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                        let statusCode = nsHTTPResponse.statusCode
                        print ("status code = \(statusCode)")
                    }
                    if let error = error {
                        print ("\(error)")
                    }
                    if let data = data {
                        do{
                        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
                        let deviceId = jsonData["deviceId"] as! String
                        let mobileDeviceId = jsonData["mobileDeviceId"] as! String
                        let deviceType = jsonData["deviceType"] as! String
                        print (" deviceId= \(deviceId), mobileDeviceId= \(mobileDeviceId), deviceType= \(deviceType)")
                        }catch _ {
                            print ("the response is not well JSON formatted")
                        }
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
            }catch _ {
                print ("Oops something happened buddy")
            }
```

If you want to try, this is the Java web service code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
@Path("/putMethodTest")
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response putMethodTest(String requestString) {
        JSONObject requestJSON = new JSONObject(requestString);
        String deviceId = requestJSON.getString("deviceId");
        String mobileDeviceId = requestJSON.getString("mobileDeviceId");
        String deviceType = requestJSON.getString("deviceType");
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put("deviceId", deviceId);
        response.put("mobileDeviceId", mobileDeviceId);
        response.put("deviceType", deviceType);
        return Response.ok().entity(response.toString()).build();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Define the put function like this :

```
//
// Put request
//
static func put(path: String, accessToken: Bool, data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, finish: (accessTokenX:String, data: JSON) -> ()) {
    apiRequest("PUT", path: path, accessToken: accessToken, contentType: nil, data: data) { (accessTokenX:String, data: AnyObject) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            finish(accessTokenX:accessTokenX, data: JSON(data))
        })
    }
}
```

An example of use :

```
    //
    // Update informations of the profile
    //
    static func accountUpdate(profile: [String: AnyObject], finish: (accessTokenX:String, data: JSON) -> ()) {
        let dataProfile = ["profile": profile]
        API.put("/users/profile", accessToken: true, data: dataProfile) { accessTokenX, data in finish(accessTokenX:accessTokenX, data: data)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this!!!

http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/

```
func data_request()
{
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

    let paramString = "data=Hello"
    request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (
        let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(dataString)

    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: I have to call api with put method. So please send Api call with Http PUT method

Comment: @IOS developer I gave the hint how it works so do the down vote think before on that and try out self

Comment: OP asked for a PUT, not a POST